# Getting the difference between two pandas dataframe using lamda

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, lambda

I have the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

new = {'name': ['Sheldon', 'Penny', 'Amy', 'Bernadette', 'Raj', 'Howard'],
                'episodes': [42, 24, 31, 29, 37, 40],
                'gender': ['male', 'female', 'female', 'female', 'male', 'male']}
old = {'name': ['Sheldon', 'Penny', 'Amy', 'Bernadette', 'Raj', 'Howard'],
                'episodes': [12, 32, 31, 32, 37, 40],
                'gender': ['male', 'female', 'female', 'female', 'male', 'male']}    

df1 = pd.DataFrame(new, columns = ['name','episodes', 'gender'])    
df = pd.DataFrame(old, columns = ['name','episodes', 'gender'])

a =df.merge(df1[['name','episodes']],on=['name','episodes'],how='left',indicator=True).loc[lambda x : x['_merge']=='left_only']
```

This is great as it highlights only entries where changes have been made.

Is there any way on the same line of code i can add a column with difference in episodes? Currently i am doing a for loop with `.str.contains[]` but still is very slow. I am looking for a lambda function which could do this.

Comment: Why do you group by `episodes` if you want to find differences?

Comment: @Corralien - That is joining on two columns to find where they are different. A very complicated way for `df.assign(diff=df1.episodes - df.episodes).query('diff != 0')` assuming the dataframes are aligned.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny. I updated my answer with your idea of `.query` to avoid to create a lambda function to evaluate the `.loc`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `set_index` if there is no duplicate names:

```
>>> df1.assign(episodes_diff=df1.set_index('name')['episodes']
                                .sub(df.set_index('name')['episodes'])
                                .values) \
       .loc[lambda x : x['episodes_diff'].ne(0)]

         name  episodes  gender  episodes_diff
0     Sheldon        42    male             30
1       Penny        24  female             -8
3  Bernadette        29  female             -3
```

**Note**: you can replace `.loc[...]` by `.query('episodes_diff != 0')` as suggested by @MichaelSzczesny which is more elegant and clear.